# Cannot get hyperlinks in elsart.cls documents

Tags: hyperref

When formatting a document with the class [`elsart.cls`](http://www.ipnl.in2p3.fr/nufact99/elsart.cls) provided by Elsevier, hyperlinks to sections, equations, items... don't work.

I know that `elsart.cls` is supposed to be obsoleted by `elsarticle` (most notably, it is not in CTAN anymore, while `elsarticle` is). But some journals still require it (read "*they provide an add-on package which fails with a lot of errors if used with `elsarticle` instead of `elsart`*").

MWE:

```
\documentclass{elsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
  \title{The title}
  \author{The author}
  \address{The address}

  \begin{abstract}
    ...
  \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Section}
\label{sec1}

This is a reference without an hyperlink: \ref{sec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope the tagging is appropriate: the tag [elsart](/questions/tagged/elsart) did not exist, but this question is specifically about `elsart`, excluding `elsarticle`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `frontmatter` environment: if there is no frontmatter, links work just fine.

In the definition of the environment, they open a `NoHyper` environment, but they do not close it. Adding `\endNoHyper` after the `frontmatter` fixes the problem. There is probably a cleaner solution, patching the environment, but since this environment is only supposed to appear once in the document, it is not really necessary.

Apart from the name of the environment and the fact that closing it fixes the problem, I have no idea why this works: `NoHyper` is defined with

```
\newenvironment{NoHyper}{}{}
```

so I don't understand how it has any impact on the resulting document.

But... it works:

```
\documentclass{elsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
  \title{The title}
  \author{The author}
  \address{The address}

  \begin{abstract}
    ...
  \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}
\endNoHyper % Magic!

\section{Section}
\label{sec1}

This is a reference with an hyperlink: \ref{sec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]